# Delete specific rows based on certain conditions in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to clean my data, basically I have my data -

**dataframe -**

```
d = {'User': ['Mansi kinney', 'Mansi kinney', 'Mansi kinney', 'Alley Huff', 'Alley Huff', 'Alley Huff',  Raedden Grip', 'Raedden Grip',  'S.Sarkar',
                              'S.Sarkar', 'S.Sarkar'],
                      'Work': ['', '', '', 'College', 'College', 'College', '', '', 'Business', 'Business', 'Business'],
                      'Country': ['Aus', 'Aus', 'Australia', 'US','US', 'US', 'Ban', 'Ban',
                                 'Ind', 'Ind', 'Ind'],
                      'Dept': ['Safety', 'Safety', 'Safety', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
                      'Training': ['', 'Internal', '', '', 'External', '', '', '', '', 'Internal', ''],
                      'Status': ['', '', 'Active', '', '', 'Active', '', 'Active', '', '', '']
        }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    df
```

Here I want to delete the rows where the more no. Of cells are blank and the data is scattered so I want it to be in a single row and delete the unnecessary repitition of rows

**My output should be-**

```
d = {'User':['Mansi kinney','Alley Huff','Raedden Grip', 'S.Sarkar'],
'Work': ['', 'College', '', 'Business'],
'Country': ['Aus', 'US', 'Ban',  'Ind'],
'Dept': ['Safety', '', '', ''],
                      'Training':['Internal','External', '', 'Internal'],
'Status':['Active','Active','Active', 'Active']
        }
    df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
    df
```

I have typed the whole thing in my smartphone so please let me know if the question is clear or not. Please help me to clean the data and get the desired output. Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can groupby 'User' and aggregate with ' '.join and remove duplicates with unique():

```
df = df.groupby('User').agg(lambda x: ''.join(x.unique()))
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

print(df)  
#output:
           User      Work       Country    Dept  Training  Status
0    Alley Huff   College            US          External  Active
1  Mansi kinney            AusAustralia  Safety  Internal  Active
2  Raedden Grip                     Ban                    Active
3      S.Sarkar  Business           Ind          Internal
```

**UPDATE:** Here it is with your full data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_excel('your_data.xls')
df = df.groupby('user').agg(lambda x: ''.join(x.unique()))
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
print(df)

#output:
                   user                                              works  \
0        Abhishek Mitra  Director & CEO | INDIAN CYBER SECURITY SOLUTIO...   
1         Anandita Kaul       HR Associate - Recruitments at Pulp Strategy   
2         Glam Sorvey.B    Data Science & Analytics with Python Consultant   
3   Madhurima S. Sarkar  MBA in Business Analytics and Finance || The S...   
4         Mansi Makhija                                    Works at Amazon   
5       NanaoSana Singh  DevOps | AWS | Docker | Kubernetes | Git | Jen...   
6         Neeraj Mishra                               DGM at Pulp Strategy   
7       Niral Shahpatel  Scale and Strategy Lead - Global Partner Marke...   
8      Sandhya Ramagiri     Technical Program Manager at Intel Corporation   
9         Sarthak Ahuja         Associate Account Manager at Pulp Strategy   
10         UDIT NARAYAN          Student at Narula Institute Of Technology   

                             country  
0        Kolkata, West Bengal, India  
1          South Delhi, Delhi, India  
2    Portland, Oregon, United States  
3        Kolkata, West Bengal, India  
4        Noida, Uttar Pradesh, India  
5           Pune, Maharashtra, India  
6                              India  
7   Hillsboro, Oregon, United States  
8    Austin, Texas Metropolitan Area  
9                       Delhi, India  
10       Domchanch, Jharkhand, India
```

Comment: pakpe thanks for your reply...so I have copied your code and tried but I don't get my desired output with another set of data in same format,

Comment: Post the other data and desired output.

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9aa12a7b9b60341f2a80647e347a850920210315135517/05349d

Comment: Sir , I have added we transfer link...there you will find I/p A and o/p A and also for B. I have added a sheet named logic where I have explained what exactly I want as my output. Not every dataset has exactly the same format , but a slight change is there but logic is somehow same. I want a very robust code which will giver me desired output for that logic

Comment: Sir I have added the link, pls go through it within 7 days

Comment: I tried it with your full data.  It seems to work perfectly as expected.  See my updated answer.

Comment: Sir but **linkage** and **about** columns are missing..I need all the columns in my output

Comment: Sir please check..I have added a new comment above

Comment: That's because your new data set is inconsistently filled.  Unlike the first 3 columns, the Linkage column has missing values.  The real problem is the About column, which has missing values both within and between user groups.  This requires an entirely different strategy which goes way beyond the scope of the original question.  The appropriate course of action for you would be to accept this solution, since it answered the original question, and post your new dataset as a whole new question.  Then I and others will consider spending some more time on this.

Comment: But, the question which I have posted in that Also it contains missing values in almost every row like the last two rows training and status column have...

Comment: Re-read what I said about the ‘About’ column. Without going into more detail, this dataset is very different from the original one and can not be solved with the same strategy. If you want an answer, post a new question.

Comment: Ok sir, sorry for misunderstanding your comment ☺️, will post another question, just I want a favor, would you mind if I ask you to give a proper heading for that question? I messed up with my own problem, what to write n what not to write :(

Comment: How to collapse dataframe to eliminate redundant rows.

Comment: Thanks for your help sir